# How can I protect a mobile application from LogJam?

Tags: tls, android, ios

I develop a two-factor authentication app on iOS and Android and I recently noticed that they run perfectly fine against a local dev server that is vulnerable to LogJam. Is there any way to secure these apps to not allow connections to LogJam vulnerable servers? Is this a reasonable concern?

Comment: I think you would have to custom code a check for the LogJam vuln and block connection attempts. If I am correct, this is a programming problem/solution.

Comment: Is this likely how Firefox solved it with the last update? Is it much of a concern from the client side?